# Média de itens com critérios diferentes

Tags: ionic

Tenho essa funções que soma os preços dos itens de um `array`

```
somaTotal() {

  let criterioPorIdpv = {};
  let criteriosComPrecos = [];

  // Parte 1: Monta um criterioPreco para cada criterio.
  for (let i in this.varia) {
      criteriosComPrecos.push({
          tipo: this.varia[i].tpCal,
          idPVs: this.varia[i].idPV,
          preco: 0.0
      });
  }

  // console.log(criteriosComPrecos);

  // Parte 2: Monta uma tabela de idPV para criterioPreco.
  for (let i in criteriosComPrecos) {
      let criterioPreco = criteriosComPrecos[i];
      for (let idPV in criterioPreco.idPVs) {
          criterioPorIdpv[criterioPreco.idPVs[idPV]] = criterioPreco;
      }
  }

  // console.log(criterioPorIdpv);

  // Parte 3: Acessa cada item da pizza, confere o seu valor e
  // o coloca no criterioPreco correspondente.
  for (let i in this.selectedVariation) {
      let item = this.selectedVariation[i];
      let crit = criterioPorIdpv[item.idPV];
      // console.log(crit);
      if (crit.tipo === "1") {
          let v = crit.preco;
          if (item.preco > v) crit.preco = item.preco;
      }else if (crit.tipo === "2") {
          let v = crit.preco;
          if (v == 0) {
            crit.preco = item.preco;
          }else if (item.preco < v) {
            crit.preco = item.preco;
          }
      } else if (crit.tipo === "3") {
          crit.preco += parseFloat(item.preco);

      }else if (crit.tipo === "4") {
          let v = crit.preco;
          if (v == 0) {
            crit.preco = item.preco;
          }else{
            // crit.preco = item.preco;
          }
      } else {
          throw new Error("Tipo inválido: " + crit.tipo);
      }
  }

  // Parte 4: Percorre todos os elementos criterioPreco
  // para obter o valor final.
  let total = 0;
  for (let i in criteriosComPrecos) {
      total += parseFloat(criteriosComPrecos[i].preco);
  }
  this.total = total;
  return total;
}
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo somar no seguinte critério: Quando o tipo for igual a "4" quero que ele pegue a media do valor do itens desse critério 
por que serão vários itens com critérios diferentes e não faço ideia de como fazer.

Comment: De onde estão vindo esses dados... Esses critérios do tipo "4" .. qual a estrutura deles..Tem como exemplificar mais , colocar mais informações..

Comment: Sim, o  critério do tipo "4" vem do primeiro for da função... ele busca dentro de um array de variações onde "tpCal" representa o tipo de cálculo, e coloco ele dentro do array "criteriosComPrecos" setando o "tipo" e o "idPV" do item!